# ASP.net TextBox Regular Expression Needed to include 2 Decimal Places

Tags: asp.net

Good Evening All,

I have a textbox that needs to accept 14 digits plus 2 decimal places.  Examples include:
12345678901234
12345678901234.94
.75

To this end, I have the following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox textboxRight"
    MaxLength="14" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required "
    SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgItem"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
&nbsp;

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Quantity"
    ValidationExpression="^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$" 
    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The MaxLength for this textbox is set to 14 as well.  Can anyone guide me as to how to write the regex to accept a total of 14 digits and two decimal places?

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: A really good tool for developing RegExs is Expresso, found here: http://ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm . It will show you exactly what your expression does in plain English, and provides a strong "IDE" for RegExs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eleven digits followed by (optionally) period and two more digits. This is the maximum that can fit in your field: `^\d{1,11}(?:\.\d\d)?$`

If you want the user to be able to type 14 digits without any decimals or up to 11 digits with two decimals (and not allow just a single decimal digit), you could do this: `^(?:\d{1,14}|\d{1,11}\.\d\d)$`